# D3js: Unable to translate the x-axis ticks a little bit to the right so that they don´t start from 0 in the X axis?

Tags: d3.js

I have a code which draw a bar chart. The problem is that the first `x-axis` tick starts from 0 value in the x-axis, totally stacked to left, without the smallest margin from the y-axis and,therefore, the the first bar is drawn from where the `y-axis` is drawn, which makes the cart looks terrible.

I've researched but haven't found a way to move or translate `x-axis` ticks so that the first one has a decent left margin, let's say, 10 px from the `y-axis`. How can I accomplish this?  I will leave a runnable snippet to provide more info.

```js
var data = [
  {year: 2000, population: 1192},
  {year: 2001, population: 1234},
  {year: 2002, population: 1463},
  {year: 2003, population: 1537},
  {year: 2004, population: 1334},
  {year: 2005, population: 1134},
  {year: 2006, population: 1234},
  {year: 2007, population: 1484},
  {year: 2008, population: 1562},
  {year: 2009, population: 1427},
  {year: 2010, population: 1325},
  {year: 2011, population: 1484},
  {year: 2012, population: 1661},
  {year: 2013, population: 1537},
  {year: 2014, population: 1334},
  {year: 2015, population: 1134},
  {year: 2016, population: 1200}
 ];


  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");


  function type(dataArray) {
   dataArray.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year = parseDate(d.year);
    d.retention = +d.population;
   });
   return dataArray;
  }
  data = type(data);



  var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},

   height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  var xScale = d3.scaleTime();
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale)


  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale)





  var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var artboard = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
  yScale.domain([
    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.population - 200 }), 
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population + 200 })
   ]);




  var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");


  var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
    .call(yAxis);


  function drawChart() {

   width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;


   svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

   xScale.range([0, width]);


   xAxis.scale(xScale);


   xAxisEl.call(xAxis);

   var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("class","rects2")
    .data(data);

    rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill","#BC204D").attr("y", function(d) {
     return height - yScale(d.population)
     }).merge(rects)
     .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.population);
      })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(" + (xScale(d.year) + margin.left)   + "," + margin.bottom + ")"
    })
    .attr("fill","#00338D");
    rects.exit().remove();
  }

  drawChart();

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a little date margin to your domain

```
var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; });
var msPerMonths = 30*24*60*60*1000;
extent[0] = new Date(extent[0].getTime() - msPerMonths);
extent[1] = new Date(extent[1].getTime() + 3*msPerMonths);
xScale.domain(extent);
```

```js
var data = [
  {year: 2000, population: 1192},
  {year: 2001, population: 1234},
  {year: 2002, population: 1463},
  {year: 2003, population: 1537},
  {year: 2004, population: 1334},
  {year: 2005, population: 1134},
  {year: 2006, population: 1234},
  {year: 2007, population: 1484},
  {year: 2008, population: 1562},
  {year: 2009, population: 1427},
  {year: 2010, population: 1325},
  {year: 2011, population: 1484},
  {year: 2012, population: 1661},
  {year: 2013, population: 1537},
  {year: 2014, population: 1334},
  {year: 2015, population: 1134},
  {year: 2016, population: 1200}
 ];


  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");


  function type(dataArray) {
   dataArray.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year = parseDate(d.year);
    d.retention = +d.population;
   });
   return dataArray;
  }
  data = type(data);



  var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},

   height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  var xScale = d3.scaleTime();
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale)


  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale)





  var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var artboard = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; });
    var msPerMonths = 30*24*60*60*1000;
    extent[0] = new Date(extent[0].getTime() - msPerMonths);
    extent[1] = new Date(extent[1].getTime() + 3*msPerMonths);
  xScale.domain(extent);
  yScale.domain([
    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.population - 200 }), 
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population + 200 })
   ]);




  var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");


  var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
    .call(yAxis);


  function drawChart() {

   width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;


   svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

   xScale.range([0, width]);


   xAxis.scale(xScale);


   xAxisEl.call(xAxis);

   var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("class","rects2")
    .data(data);

    rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill","#BC204D").attr("y", function(d) {
     return height - yScale(d.population)
     }).merge(rects)
     .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.population);
      })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(" + (xScale(d.year) + margin.left)   + "," + margin.bottom + ")"
    })
    .attr("fill","#00338D");
    rects.exit().remove();
  }

  drawChart();

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

or translate the yAxis

```
var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-20,0")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you. I'd really like to understand the science behind this. What these numbers are: 30*24*60*60*1000; and why do you substract them here: 
them extent[0] = new Date(extent[0].getTime() - msPerMonths); 
and why do you add them * 3  here: 
extent[1] = new Date(extent[1].getTime() + 3*msPerMonths)

Thanks.

Comment: miliseconds per months, have a look what a `Date` really is